# Is it possible to set the ssh default login user as 'root' in <user>@ip when none is set

Tags: command-line, ssh, login, root

Is there a way to set it so that when you do `ssh 123.122.123.123`. it will use the user `root` instead of your logged in user as if you did `ssh root@123.122.123.123`

so every time you specify no user, it will default to `root`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding an entry to your local `~/.ssh/config` file like

```
Hostname    123.122.123.123
User        root
```

Note that you will need to have enabled root login on the target host: I **strongly** recommend that you do **not** do so using password-based login, but instead by setting up secure key-based authentication using the default `prohibit-password` configuration

Comment: Yeah, it's just for testing environment where time need to be saved. the only issue with this though is you'd have to manually add each IP/host. so if you are dealing with many VPS servers that's gonna be an ouch.

Comment: @basod3 you could use a pattern to specify multiple hosts in a single stanza - please refer to the `PATTERNS` section of `man ssh_config`